# SQLite query to get two dimenational records(students vs quiz)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am new in sqlite, I have three tables, Students, quiz and mark sheet. i want to write all data in CVS with single sqlite query. I want to remove multiples for loops and condition from code and handle with single query. I created query in sql but i don't understand how it should be in SQLlite. it seems like two dimensional(number of students vs number of quizzes). 
Student table:

```
Id | StudentId | Name       
1  | 001       | ABC

2  | 002       | EFG

3  | 003       | XYZ
```

Quiz table:

```
QId |TotalMark | Question    

1   |   10     | ABC

2   |   10     | TUI

3   |   10     | LMP
```

Marksheet table :

```
SId   | QID | Marks

001   |   1 | 4

002   |   1 | 6

003   |   1 | 7

001   |   2 | 5

002   |   2 | 6

003   |   2 | 7

001   |   3 | 9

002   |   3 | 6

003   |   3 | 7
```

Required OUTPUT IS:

```
Id | StudentId | Name | ABC | TUI|  LMP

1  | 001       | ABC  |  4  | 5  |  6

2  | 002       | EFG  |  4  | 5  |  6

3  | 003       | XYZ  |  4  | 5  |  6

DROP TABLE  H;
DROP TABLE  T;
SELECT TOP 1 
        STUFF(( SELECT ', '  + M.title 
                FROM    dbo.marksheet M
                        INNER JOIN marksheet_item MI ON M.marksheet_id = MI.marksheet_id
                        INNER JOIN dbo.student SS ON SS.stu_id = MI.stu_id
                WHERE   S.stu_id = SS.stu_id
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 2, '') AS ReportHeader
INTO    H
FROM    student S
GROUP BY S.stu_id,S.stu_name;

SELECT  MIN(stu_id) AS ID ,
        S.stu_id ,S.stu_name,
        STUFF(( SELECT ', '  + CAST(MI.marks AS VARCHAR(50))
                FROM    dbo.marksheet M
                        INNER JOIN marksheet_item MI ON M.marksheet_id = MI.marksheet_id
                        INNER JOIN dbo.student SS ON SS.stu_id = MI.stu_id
                WHERE   S.stu_id = SS.stu_id
              FOR
                XML PATH('')
              ), 1, 2, '') AS report
INTO    t
FROM    student S
GROUP BY S.stu_id,S.stu_name;

SELECT  *FROM    h;
SELECT  *FROM    t;
```

Comment: @sagar, Thanks for formatting, how you format tables?

Comment: Using Ctrl+Shift+K

Comment: Looks to me you need to pivot your data into the output

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

SQLite operates locally. So there is no network latency, very few transaction problems and so on, which is the reason you would want to avoid multiple queries in a typical DBMS and rather execute such complex statements.

In SQLite the overhead of creating and deleting tables and interpreting complex queries is relatively large, compared to just writing the logic in code. You can without problems [fire hundreds of queries select without running into performance issues](http://www.sqlite.org/np1queryprob.html).

Also creating and deleting tables, or any data at all, just bloats the storage file, because SQLite does not delete until you execute an explicit cleanup.